# How to extend a Map in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

What I am trying to do is to write a custom class extending `Map[DateTime, T]`. The extended class is to take a `Map[DateTime, T]` as a constructor argument and call corresponding methods of the supplied map for every method a `Map` is to implement.

I had no problem writing

```
def -(key: DateTime) = iv.-(key)
def get(key: DateTime) = iv.get(key)
```

but I've got stuck on

```
+[B1 :>B](kv: (A, B1)):Map[A, B1]
```

How am I meant to write it?

Isn't there a simple reference `Map` wrapper implementation to start from?

PS: Don't offer to declare it as `type DtMap[T] = Map[DateTime, T]` - I am going to have to add my own methods into the class.

UPDATE: So, the result looks like this, to consolidate it so that somebody would be able to use it as a starting point for his `Map` extension (may the solution have some hidden problems - please let me know):

```
case class DtValMap[T](iv: Map[DateTime, T]) extends Map[DateTime, T] {
  def -(key: DateTime) = new DtValMap(iv.-(key))
  def get(key: DateTime) = iv.get(key)
  def +[T1 >: T](kv: (DateTime, T1)): DtValMap[T1] = new DtValMap(iv + kv)
  def iterator: Iterator[(DateTime, T)] = iv.iterator
}
```

UPDATE2: I've noticed the typo which was causing the problem now: I had `:>` (wrong) instead of `>:`. But I intentionally don't correct it in the text above as it would make the question make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is

```
class YourMap[T](iv: Map[DateTime, T]) extends Map[DateTime, T]
```

Can't you just do

```
def +[T1 >: T](kv: (DateTime, T1)): YourMap[T1] = new YourMap(iv + kv)
```

I'm not too sure about your `def -`,  If I understand correctly, it returns a Map, not a YourMap. If this is ok, why can't you do just the same for `+`?

In the line of `type DtMap[T]`, have you considered adding the method with pimp my library, rather than with class extension? Collection classes are complex, and so is extending them.

Comment: I just couldn't understand all the complexity. I can feel what the + argumentation is meant to mean but I don't exactly know what is `:>`. I was returning a `Map` because I didn't knew how to write it to return `YourMap`. What about "pimp my library" - I am not sure if such approach can be adequate for a library's main fundamental types.

Comment: By the way `+` still doesn't work this way: `wrong number of type arguments`, `not found: type A`, `not found: type B`.

Comment: sorry, was a bit too fast with it. fixed

Comment: >: is not complex, it just needs you to look it up.

Comment: Curious. I've tried it this way (With T1, T and DateTime), but it was broken too. But now it seems ok.

Comment: Unfortunately Google doesn't seem able to search for `:>` and I can't figure out in what a type is it defined, @gpampara

Comment: "Collection classes are complex, and so is extending them." - how is it complex if I was only to implement 4 methods? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ivan have a look at symbolhound.com to search for the symbol. Otherwise you could check the scala references :)

Comment: How is it complex ? Doing it right is complex. e.g, even if in the 4 methods, you are careful to return YourMap, all the inherited methods will keep returning Map.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [`MapProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.MapProxy)? *This has been deprecated on Scala 2.11, so this particular solution should be avoided.*

Anyway, if you insist on extending `Map` and providing all of its API, what exactly is the problem with implementing `+`? Why doesn't this work?

```
def +[B1 >: T](kv: (DateTime, B1)):Map[DateTime, B1] = new YourMap(iv + kv)
```

Comment: By the way, could you tell what does `+` in `MapProxy[A, +B]` mean? Following your recommendation, I am studying `MapProxy` right now - maybe it can happen to be a better solution for the case of mine.

Comment: @Ivan It means `MapProxy` is covariant in `B`. Or, in other words, that if `C` is a subtype of `B`, then `MapProxy[A, C]` is a subtype of `MapProxy[A, B]`. If you have experience with Java, it might help to know that all Java generics are invariant (ie, do not have this property), while Java's `Array` is covariant. Ironically, as it happens, because it is not type-sound for `Array` to be covariant.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, isn't it my initial typo in your answer? I mean shouldn't it be `>:` rather than `:>` there?

Comment: @Ivan I copy&pasted the signature from your question, so if it was wrong there, it is wrong here. :-)

Comment: That is what made me to ask the question and the answer on your "Why doesn't this work?" :-)

Comment: MapProxy has been deprecated since Scala 2.11.0 so you should probably now avoid using it if you can.